# git repo reorganization via branch

Tags: git

To date, I'd not used branches, but tags to as development has been mostly serial. But, I need to do some major changes, and considering a branch - actually I've already started the prototype in a non-git working path but want to fold it back into git as a branch.

So, what I'd like to do now is to

1. create new branch blNew
2. adopt the prototype path as the blNew edits
3. continue along with blNew until
4. bring it back to master

So far I've

```
git checkout -b blNew
```

in my current working path, but here I'm unsure how to proceed.

How to inject the 'stage' path as my blNew branch keeping separate my working path (to master) intact?

After eventual branch merging, I would pull blNew into my master working path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With git you can one of two things. You can either use `git worktree` to have two separate working directories for your two different branches from the same repository, or you can switch forth and back between different branches in the same working directory by using `git checkout`. Which way you go is totally up to you as you prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all of your work from the other path into your the location of your git repo. Make sure to leave the `.git` folder (it may be hidden on your system). After copying you should be able to run `git status` and it will show all the modifications that have been made.

From this point you can commit this change as normal and continue working. When your feature is done, switch back to master `git checkout master` and you can merge your branch in with `git merge blNew`

Comment: I'm uneasy mucking the existing work path so I was thinking to do something along these lines like
1. git clone ...
2. copy files from stage to new clone

Comment: @slashlos a new branch is essentially the same as git clone. Anything you do on the branch will stay on the branch and when you go back to master everything will be untouched. But the git clone example would work as well